# Change price format from dot (.) to Comma (,) in python

Tags: python, pandas

Iam using python's pandas dataframe to create a csv from a txt file.
This txt file has a price in dot format eg 23.45

In my csv I want the out in comma format, like 23,45.

I tried the following but failed to achieve the end result:

1. Replace the particular column's (.) to (,)
   -> Result:  Whole numbers is gone, new cell has value "None".
2. Try locale for EUR but got a currency sign € at the end. Which i couldnt found a way to remove too.
3. Tried Lambda function to format. Still didn't achieved the result.

Below are the tried methods I used.

```
 1. df['price'] = df['price'].replace('.',',', inplace= True)
 2. locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE')
   df['price'] = df['price'].apply(locale.currency)
 3. df['price'] = df['price'].apply(lambda y: '{:.,2f}'.format(y))
```

Please help me out where I was missing.

Comment: please show the df your working with, along with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You almost got it. Just had to convert the `float` to `str` and then apply `str.replace`.

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype(str).str.replace('.',',')
```

Input:

```
   price
0  20.12
1  10.12
2  34.12
3  35.43
```

Output (After running the code)

```
   price
0  20,12
1  10,12
2  34,12
3  35,43
```